# Why doesn't the windows registry know how to interpret or expand %temp%?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a registry entry in the Run key as follows:

type = REG_SZ,
value = test,
data = %temp%\test.exe

When I reboot my machine test.exe does not run, but if I do the full path of the temp folder (something like "C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Local Settings\Temp") then it does run it upon reboot.

What's up with this?

I also tried type of REG_EXPAND_SZ but it still didn't work.

Comment: Using `REG_EXPAND_SZ` *should* work for the Run key. Try opening a command-prompt and running the command `set temp`. Does it show the variable expanded? Try opening an elevated command-prompt and repeat. Does it expand the variable now?

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out it was a mistake on my part. I reverted my VMWare image and now it's working fine.

Comment: If you solve the problem on your own: either post your own answer describing the solution, or close the question as "no longer relevant".

Answer (score 1):

The registry is just a database of information - it is not an application which can 'interpret' its own content.

I can see no reason why this shouldn't be possible.  Maybe you could create a small batch file that echos %TEMP% to a file at bootup to see what, if anything, is in there?

Comment: Actually, the environment in Windows is initialized by the session management subsystem which occurs early in the boot sequence. This means that all variables should be available for expansion by the time that Explorer runs and launches the items in the Run key (which definitely knows to run ExpandEnvironmentVariables() on the values).

Comment: That's good to know

Answer (score 1):

What about surrounding the data in quotes?

Comment: Good point. Explorer uses `ShellExecute` to start the "`Run`" entries, to allow for command arguments, etc.; it's possible that it would attempt to start `C:\Documents` in this case.

Comment: Not likely. Brian said that he is using the `temp` variable which is the system temporary directory, which is usually in `C:\Windows\Temp` (which has neither spaces nor long names). The users’ local temp directory is stored in the `tmp` variable. So unless he specifically changed the system temp-directory variable to point to a directory in his own folder, spaces *should* not be an issue.

Comment: @Synetech: In all systems I have seen, both `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` point to the *user's* temporary directory.

Comment: Strange. Check the registry and you *should* see that `temp` is defined in **HKLM** with a reference to `systemroot` and `tmp` is defined in **HKCU** with a reference to `localappdata`.

Comment: @Synetech: I checked Windows 2008 Server, Windows XP Pro and Windows 2000 Pro: Both `TEMP` and `TMP` are defined per-user (`HKCU\Environment` pointing to user profile subdirectory) **and** system-wide (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` pointing to `%SystemRoot%\Temp`).

Comment: That sounds about right more or less. The user version overrides the system one. I suppose programs like installers that need to work outside the user’s circle get the system-level variables. (It seems like more work than simply using different variables, but then that’s yet more backwards-compatibility for you.)

Comment: @Synetech: The system-wide Temp directory is mostly for services running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. (I haven't checked Windows Installer, but it _seems_ like it loads the user's environment. By the way, about a half of the services run under `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` or `NETWORK SERVICE` accounts, which have their own temp directories too.)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your %temp% variable in quotes. The space in the path may be throwing something off.

data = "%temp%"\test.exe

Comment: Spaces should not matter in the context of a Run key entry unless there are command-line arguments, which the question does not include. Trust me, I’ve experimented.

Comment: True, unless there happens to be a "C:\Documents"... (I believe Explorer _warns_ if a "C:\Program" exists along with "C:\Program Files".)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `%temp%` even points to the folder that you think it does.

Comment: Where are you finding these mysterious machines whose user accounts expand %temp% to C:\Windows\Temp? 1998?

Comment: User accounts don’t expand it to the system temp folder, they expand it to the local folder. Users have their own environment variables that override the system-wide one.